# kafka consumer is not listening from command line

Tags: apache-kafka

I am using kafka 1.0.0V In my project. From yesterday on wards. I am unable to listen Messages from command line . In the same time I am able to listen the messages from Kafka tool. In the same time My applications are also not consuming the data. Is there any issue in kafka.

This is the command i am using to consume the messages

```
/usr/hdp/2.6.0.3-8/kafka/bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server hostname:6667 --topic test --from-beginning
```

topic create,describe,produce command are working from commandline

Comment: Make sure that the kafka topic is not empty. Try running the following command to see if the topic is empty or not.
Command 1 : /usr/hdp/2.6.0.3-8/kafka/bin/kafka-run-class.sh kafka.tools.GetOffsetShell --broker-list hostname:6667 --topic test --time -1 --offsets 1 .     
Command 2 : /usr/hdp/2.6.0.3-8/kafka/bin/kafka-run-class.sh kafka.tools.GetOffsetShell --broker-list hostname:6667 --topic test --time -2 --offsets 1 .     
If the offset values are same in both the outputs, the topic is empty.

Comment: Now I am able to consume the data from command linr. The problem is I was using 6667 port before . I tried with zookeeper port Now i am receving data in command line. But my applications(NIFI) Still not listening the data.

Comment: What do you have in config(group id , reset offset)?

Comment: groupid= test-consumer-group;auto.offset.reset=latest